# PHP show result and (if)condition

Tags: php

My Question is how can i show the flag image near the country name for each users after add it in db and show the result , 
what i mean i use :

```
<div class="clear-both"><?php echo $result[$i]["country"]; ?></div>
```

and in page result just print the country name you can see in attached photo

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOkmG.gif]

how can i add flag with each country name

Comment: show the data associated with that *flag*

Comment: This question has at least a million responses everywhere tho...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - you need all the country flags somewhere.
Step 2 - just let PHP print out the country name into a image tag like this:

```
<img src="your/image/folder/<?php echo $country; ?>" alt="<?php echo $country; ?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to save the country flags in a folder for example `images/flags` and name the flags after the country name (`belgium.png`), then use following code

```
<?php $country = echo $result[$i]["country"]; ?>
<img src="images/flags/<?php print $country; ?>.png">
<p><?php print $country; ?></p>
```

Comment: please can you help me how can i use switch in this case